# In a world like the one described, in what kinds of environments could a metal like Skarilium occur naturally?

Tags: technology, materials, metals

In a [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/235407/is-it-possible-for-a-metal-like-the-skarilium-of-my-works-to-exist-naturally-whi), I described a purely-fictional metal that was lightweight and impossibly durable, saying it existed in a world not far off from real life in terms of physics. However, I’ve since realized that that world’s physics aren’t as similar to real life’s as I thought. An example of this is that Magic exists in this world and is, on some life-harboring planets, very significant to the way life is lived.

So, I figured I’d ask a refined version of that question.

Either way, for this question in particular, there are two things I need to say:

- First, Skarilium is still just as lightweight and just as enduring as it was previously.
- Second, Skarilium has been revamped to be the result of a process that’s basically an equivalent to the concept of evolution in which a chemical element becomes an entirely different element by gaining the properties of another element, but does not become a compound. For instance, Skarilium is a distant relative of the element known as Specium that is a metal because of it gaining the properties of other metals, particularly Titanium, Iron, Aluminum, and Tungsten.

About that second point, here’s a list of all the elements required to create  Skarilium:

- Specium
- Titanium
- Iron
- Silver
- Cobalt
- Carbon

Now, given these changes, what kind of environments could Skarilium occur in naturally?

By the way, keep in mind that I’m not asking if Skarilium could exist in real life, anymore. It’s clear that it couldn’t.

Also, I intend to make it clear that Skarilium is not a chemical compound or an alloy: it’s an element. Yes, it’s Specium with properties gained from other elements, but Specium has a property that allows it to combine with other elements without becoming a compound, or at least what’s traditionally considered a compound. Also, I do know that’s very contradictory to real world physics.

Edit #1: I’ve replaced Tungsten and Aluminum with Copper and Silver.

Edit #2: I’ve removed Copper from the list and added another note.

Comment: I think pure unalloyed Specium ought to give you all the properties you need, and also turn up where your characters are looking to find it.

Comment: *"I’m not asking if Skarilium could exist in real life"*, but I am asking *"what kind of environments could Skarilium occur in naturally"*. There is a contradiction there. Skarilium cannot exist in our world, naturally or artificially, doesn't matter. In what environments it can be found in your *fictional* world, it is entirely up to you. I for one would suggest that it be naturally abundant not far from those places frequented by adventurers who need skarilium smiths to forge their skarilium accoutrements. Or maybe it occurs only in the dark blue mountains of the sinister enemy empire. Etc.

Comment: (The main problem being that aluminium is only *extremely* rarely found in its metallic form, and just about never ever in association with native iron. In the real world there is no environment where one can find both native iron and native aluminium. And I have never heard of any native tungsten *at all*.)

Comment: Thing is, Specium isn’t naturally a metal. It’s an ore that turns into a metal through the process of becoming Skarilium. Specium has its own properties which change when it becomes Skarilium. An example is that Specium is highly energetic and releases all of its energy at room temperature, which is a property Skarilium doesn’t have.

Comment: @AlexP, I didn’t see what you said there until after posting that comment.

Comment: My comment is related to the requirment that specium gains its properties from <list of metals> and carbon. To gain their properties, it must be in contact (or at least close to) those metals in their metallic form, otherwise it makes no sense. For example, alumimium metal is *extremely* rare: only tiny amounts exist in very special environments; almost all aluminium is found in compounds, such as alumina and aluminosilicates, very different materials with very different properties. How can specium *guess* the properties of aluminium when aluminium is in the form of an aluminosilicate?

Comment: Honestly, I didn’t look into how aluminum occurs naturally. Same goes for the other metals in the list.

Comment: The only one I actually knew anything about how it occurs was Specium, which occurs as a mineral on Mars.

Answer (score 1):

**Lava Floes**

[image]

*Volcano Scientist Katie Atkins. Photo from [The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/photo/2016/08/lava-flows-from-hawaiis-kilauea-volcano/497918/#img01).*

Your imaginary metal is a magical alloy of several real metals. Alloys are rare in nature. I cannot think of a single example. So you need some energetic and exciting process to create the Skarilium from ingredients.

I suggest the special metal forms near volcanoes. All the iron and titanium and cobalt and stuff already exists in the soil. This part is real. Iron and aluminium can be extracted from soil. When the lava rolls over the special mixture these compounds melt and combine into lumps of Skarilium. Hooray!

When the flow hardens it is a race to dig out the Skarilium and get rich. Some people are over-eager and start digging when they only THINK the flow has hardened and get a faceful of lava. Hijinks ensue!

Comment: *'Alloys are rare in nature":* All metals which occur in native form also occur as alloys with other native metals. Probably the best known natural alloy is [electrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrum), which was abundant enough for the Ancient Egyptians to use it to coat the pyramidions topping their obelisks and for the ancient Lydians and Ionians to use it for the oldest coins in the world.

Comment: @AlexP How does the electrum form in nature?

Comment: Electrum is a gold and silver alloy. Both gold and silver occur as native metals; gold almost always, silver usually. Electrum occurs when the process which concentrates gold or silver operated on a primordial source which contained both gold and silver -- there is no natural process which would separate them.